# how to install pyaudio module in google cloud shell?

Tags: pyaudio

Error:

```
raise AttributeError("Could not find PyAudio; check installation")
AttributeError: Could not find PyAudio; check installation
```

I tried all of these commands:

```
sudo pip install pyaudio,
sudo apt-get install python-pyaudio ,
sudo pip install pyaudio ,
sudo pip install --upgrade pyaudio.
```

Answer (score 0):

First, undo what you have done.

Then try to install it following their [documentation](http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/) for Debian based versions:

`$ sudo apt install portaudio19-dev python-all-dev`

followed by

`$ sudo apt install python-pyaudio` for python 2 version

**OR**

`$ sudo apt install python-pyaudio` for python 3 version.

Comment: Hi @KhushalReddy if this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.